# Where does this hyperbolic tangent in Nakahara's text come from?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, partition-function

I don't see why the term with $\tanh$ appears in the equation 1.164

The textbook is the second edition of *Geometry, Topology and Physics*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Eq. (1.163) represents only the **quantum** fluctuations in the path integral for the partition function $Z(\beta)={\rm Tr} e^{-\beta H},$ while the $\tanh$ term in eq. (1.164) comes from the **classical** contributions when integrating over possible boundary conditions for the classical paths, cf. eq. (1.151).

Comment: Using 1.164 we only have the second term in 1.139. Then we integrate like in 1.151. Are this correct?